# Flash Air / Android: native extension testing

Tags: android, flash, air-native-extension

I am building my native Android extension for Flash. I just finished building my Android library.

How do I test it now?

- I want to test it under Android only
- I want to test it under flash

What is the best practice? Can I debug when testing in flash?

Answer (score 0):

Flash player not supported native extensions. You can use it only in AIR runtime for Windows, OSX, Android and IOS.
If your extension created for android you can test it only on android device in AIR application.
You can debug your android application on device with your ide, and you can see java logs by Log class. For example: Log.i("some log info"); Use [android ddms tool](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html) for see this logs.

[Read this info](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS597e5dadb9cc1e0253f7d2fc1311b491071-8000.html)